# How can I generate an XML using Perl and XSLT?

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I want to generate an XML file using Perl and XSLT. Is it possible to achieve this by updating the XSLT dynamically by uusing values from a hash?

Or is there any better solution for wirting a simple XML file using Perl?

Comment: That depends on how simple you mean. An example might help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "It depends" but generally "Simple" XML can be printed directly from Perl data structiures using XML::Simple module's XMLOut.

For more complicated use XML::Writer.

You can read more on handling of XML in Perl (including printing it) in Perl and XML O'Reilly book - for examples see Chapter 3 online (XML::Writer part): http://oreilly.com/catalog/perlxml/chapter/ch03.html

Also look at Perl-XML FAQ: http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is not for generating XML, it is merely for transforming XML. There's a comparison of the XML interfaces available to Perl on [O'Reily's XML site](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/18/perlxmlqstart1.html)

Comment: A 2001 article. Have things not moved on a bit since then?

Comment: Not with the XML standard, so these methods will still generate valid XML - agreed, there may be easier ways if your particular installation has kept up with all the pre-requisite libraries for some of the (arguably) simpler options that have come about since then. The article does use an example of generating XML from a hash, per the OP's request, though